# How can I get areal view screenshots of google earth images for multiple coordinates

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I am trying to download lot of google earth areal and satellite view screenshots for each coordinates i got(more that 500). I am not sure how can I automate this. After some research i found some ways which include bing maps, Google api or javascript, But no one mentioned how to go ahead with that. Can someone suggest me a way to do this? 
 Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Capturing and storing the imagery from Bing and Google Maps is against their respective terms of use and should not be done. This is likely why you are finding little information on how to do this.

Comment: Ho thank you. I didnt know that. Can you suggest me any app that i can buy to do this?

Comment: Maybe try contacting digital globe: https://www.digitalglobe.com/ They provide most of the satellite and aerial imagery for both mapping platforms.